# Could not find a setter for property

Tags: c#

I wrote this property and getting error that it could not find setter property and when i add setter i get an error "Must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, external or partial"

```
public virtual string InsuredStatus
    {
        get
        {
            string status;
            if (ExpDt > _now)
            {
                status = "ACTIVE";
                return status;
            }

            if (ExpDt < _now)
            {
                status = "EXPIRED";
                if (status == "EXPIRED" && _insuredHistory.Opertion == "M")
                {
                    return "MERGED";
                }
                return status;
            }
            return string.Empty;

        }
    }
```

Can someone point out the error in my ways and also give me a brief explanation as to what I am doing wrong and why it is throwing this error?

Comment: Are you implementing an interface? It would really help if you'd give a short but *complete* example.

Comment: So you get the error message when you are adding the setter? What does the setter look like?

Comment: i added set; like that

Answer (score 4):

Since your get has a body, C# assumes that you setter needs one too. So when you add your setter you'll need to do more than `set;` it'll have to be

```
set { /* real work here */ }
```